# value from input to next div in same fieldset

Tags: jquery

how can i paste value from input to next div?

```
<fieldset>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="my_value"></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="my_value"></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="my_value"></div>
</fieldset>
```

when user is typing I need to add this value to next div with class my_value in same fieldset and I dont know how to do it.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("input[type='text']").keyup(function() {
    $(this).next(".my_value").text(this.value);
});
```